# ASUS P5K-E motherboard upgrade to USB3.0 port

Tags: usb-3

Can I add a USB3.0 card via the PCI slot on my ASUS P5K-E motherboard and take advantage of the "SuperSpeed" of USB3.0?

The card I'm looking to buy: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816322009

Comment: You can provided you have a free PCI slot on your motherboard

Comment: [mode: nitpick] The card does not fit/work in a PCI slot. It is a PCI-e card. It will work in any of the four PCI-e slots though.

Answer (score 0):

The USB 3.0 card uses a PCI-Express x1 slot and you have two of them. The small white ones over the large blue PCI-Express x16 slot.

Install the card to one of those slots.